# SELENIUM en la intranet Python es posible un puente

Tags: javascript

En el momento se cuenta con una solución web local en Python con FRAMEWORK CHERRYPY funcionando, al desplegar la aplicación en un servidor web no funciona. Se necesita el código o función (complemento) en el navegador del usuario se le abra la URL del Reuter (MODEM) http://192.168.100.1 y rellene los campos de usuario y contraseña automáticamente.

Muestra de código en Python donde no funciona la aplicación, por que la dirección pertenece a la intranet del cliente.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python3\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://192.168.100.1/')
element = driver.find_element_by_id("txt_Username") 
element.send_keys("root") 
element = driver.find_element_by_id("txt_Password")
element.send_keys("admin")
```

cuando se ejecuta el bot selenium no tiene acceso a la intranet del cliente dirección ('http://192.168.100.1/')

Estoy buscando un puente, app, JS, o extensión para mi código Python que esta en un servidor y necesita acceso a la intranet URL del Reuter-modem ('http://192.168.100.1/'), lo importante es que en la solución no se tenga que ejecutar ningún .exe

Nota: esa app en el momento solo funciona localmente por obvias razones por las que necesito un puente entre el código Python online y el navegador del usuario. Los clientes no cuentan con la dirección ip publica para acceder desde internet.

Comment: Probaste con https?

Comment: hola gracias por responder, selenium no encuentra la ruta en el cliente por que esta dirección ('http://192.168.100.1/') pertenece a la intranet, hace falta un puente ejemplo: una dirección ip publica en este caso no tengo a la disposición.